# problem with jquery from.submit and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

below is the code i am using

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("form").submit(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

            var val = $("#captcha_text").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'checkAnswer.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: {
                    answer: val
                },
                complete: function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    if($.trim(data) == "true")
                        $("form")[0].submit();
                    else
                        alert('Wrong Answer');
                }
            });
        });
});
```

checkAnswer.php has this one line only which is

```
echo "true";
```

i do not know why the javascript if condition in the complete function is always going to else part and showing alert('Wrong Answer')

does any one know what could be the problem. ? In the firebug console i do see the response comming back from my ajax and response value is "true"

Comment: set the dataType attribute to "text" and see what happens.

Comment: i did still doesn't work .. i am gonna get patient of depression with jquery i think

Comment: Have you tried skippink the trim() function?

Comment: Does it post the "Wrong answer" alert?  Also, Did you try `$.trim(data) === "true"`?  Some things are not as equal as others.

Comment: i have tried the whole knowledge on it by changing dataType to html and text doesn't do the string comparision i have data.length = undefined and typeof(data) = object but what object is this i dont know

Comment: have you tried changing "complete" with "success"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
 if($.trim(data.responseText) == "true")
```

complete receives as 1st argument **jqXHR**(an extended XMLHTTP-Request-object) and not the  **data** depending on dataType.

Or use success instead of complete

Comment: "still not working" is not enough information for providing further help.

Comment: Thanks a lot i was stuck for 6 hours on it. and i changed the type from complete to success and its working now. Have a lovely life champ..

Comment: G molvi can you please put the form and the process you did to see the form working? I am stuck on submitting a form with jquery.

Comment: fello just remove the complete function and do all the stuff in the success function as Dr.Molle explained the complete do not receive the data object as its first argument. all the best.

Answer (score 2):

Well i think you have to do this:

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'test.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: {
                        answer: val
                    },
                    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus)
                    {   //it returns an jqXHR object
                        if($.trim(jqXHR.responseText) == "true")
                            $("form")[0].submit();
                        else
                            alert('Wrong Answer');
                    }
                });
```

This is because jQuery returns a jqXHR object look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for reference.

EDIT You can also try this:

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'test.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: {
                        answer: val
                    },
                    success: function(data)
                    {

                        if($.trim(data) == "true")
                            alert('ok');
                        else
                            alert('Wrong Answer');
                    }
                });
```

Comment: i tried it and it worked. strange. what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Are you using firefox?If you don't i suggest you use it with the firebug extension: it's perfect for debugging these problems